# Multiple <progress> elements on a page with different colors

Tags: css, html, pseudo-element

I'm using the  element and I've found good instructions on [styling] (http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/).

I'd like to have more than one progress bar on a page and I'd like them to have different fill/value colors. Is this possible? Can I do this by tweaking my CSS? Or an I better off rolling my own? Thanks!

```css
.current-roll {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  /* next line does nothing */
  color: #f7a700
}
.previous-roll {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  /* next line does nothing */
  color: #98c11e
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #d8d8d8;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #f7a700;
}
```

```html
<p>Orange bar</p>
<progress class="current-roll" value="0.5"></progress>

<p>Green bar</p>
<progress class="previous-roll" value="0.75"></progress>
```

Comment: you already have what you look for in the example you have given. use `progress.current-roll` to style the colors specifically for `.current-roll` for instance

Comment: I knew I was close, but I didn't realize how close. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`progress::-webkit-progress-value` is what changes the progress bar color.

Example

```
progress.current-roll::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #f7a700;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have what you look for in the example you have given!

use `progress.current-roll`to style the colors specifically for `.current-roll` for instance

example below:

```css
.current-roll {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  /* next line does nothing */
  color: #f7a700
}
.previous-roll {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  /* next line does nothing */
  color: #98c11e
}
progress.previous-roll::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #d8d8d8;
}
progress.previous-roll::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #f7a700;
}
progress.current-roll::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #ddd;
}
progress.current-roll::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Red bar</p>
<progress class="current-roll" value="0.5"></progress>

<p>Orange bar</p>
<progress class="previous-roll" value="0.75"></progress>
```

Comment: I saw the other answer first, which provided me with the solution. I didn't see your comment until later when I refreshed the page. Sorry!